# Why do ACL roles not appear in Reports 'Access' option menu?

Tags: civicontribute, acl, 4.6

I want to restrict access for users so that they can only see certain contributions - just those for their own campaign.  It doesn't appear to me that CiviContribute is very ACL aware, so I'm looking at producing a contribution report that is restricted in the same way.  The 'Access' part of CiviReport has a menu where I can add an 'ACL Group/Role' - but it seems that only Drupal roles appear here - not ACL roles. Is this working as designed? Or is there something I'm missing?  It appears that with contributions either a user sees everything or nothing, but I hope that isn't the case. I'm using Drupal and 4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is or was possible but as an alternative, you can :

- create a group in CiviCRM
- synchronize it with a Drupal role using CiviGroup Roles Sync (civicrm_group_roles) module (provided with CiviCRM)
- use this new role to limit access to your report

Comment: Thanks, that's a very interesting suggestion.  I must admit that I wasn't aware of group/roles sync which looks very useful.